# Power Query - Transform multiple columns at once to same format

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table in Power Query that has multiple date columns in a specific Julian Date format.
I would like to change all of them at once into the classic date format by using this function:

```
Date.AddDays(#date(Number.RoundDown([Date1]/1000)+1900,1,1),Number.Mod([Date1],1000)-1)
```

For now I doing this steps for every column:

1. Add custom column with the function above
2. Delete old column
3. Rename new column

Is there any way to do this more harmonized for all selected columns at once?

Example Data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function in Power Query.

1. New Source -> Blank Query

Than e.g. for testing you could use this example. Write in advanced editor in this new blank query:

```
let YourFormula = (input) =>
        input * 2
in YourFormula
```

Now it looks like:

[image]

In this field you can test your function.

After that you can go into your main table and add in the advanced editor at the end of code:

```
Transform = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns2", {{"PROJECTID", Query1}, {"ACCRUED", Query1}})
in
    Transform
```

This transforms the selected columns inplace. No need for adding a new one, deleting the old one and renaming.

---

**Update** according comments, now with your specific data.

Formula of the function:

```
let YourFormula = (input) =>
    Date.AddDays(#date(Number.RoundDown(input/1000)+1900,1,1),Number.Mod(input,1000)-1)
in
    YourFormula
```

Code in the main table:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQyNDAwVNIBMQxNjZRidaBiRjAxM4SYMUzMAiFmAhEzMjVQio0FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date1 = _t, Date2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date1", Int64.Type}, {"Date2", Int64.Type}}),
    Transform = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Date1", Query1}, {"Date2", Query1}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Transform,{{"Date2", type date}, {"Date1", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Table before and after:

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this really working with my function above? In the function is a variable/ placeholder for a column [Date1].

Comment: Could you provide me some test raw data, even its just a table here in SO.

Comment: Just provided some example data in the initial post

Comment: see update and let me know if it worked.